# OS X: information about custom URL schemes

Tags: macos, url-scheme

Our application makes use of special URIs, e.g. myapp://doSomething. For this purpose the `Info.plist` file contains following definition:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
   <dict>
       <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
       <string>MyApp handler</string
       <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
       <array>
          <string>myapp</string>
       </array>
   </dict>
</array>
```

Now is the problem that a couple of different versions of our application are installed and when clicking a myapp://doSomething-link some "random" version starts (using OS X 10.10.5)).

How can I see what application OS X is trying to launch (the exact path) and how can I get the choice of all applications that support this URL-schema?

Comment: Probably with `lsappinfo` but no idea how!

Comment: Thanks, Mark, `lsappinfo` at least helped me to find the path of the launched application, but how to find out all applications known to OS X with that registered URL scheme?

Comment: Maybe something with `mdfind 'kCFBundleURLScheme = "*myapp*"'`? Try `mdls` on a file associated with your app to see if you can find something.